# Are metadata reads counted in Firebase Storage pricing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

The Firebase pricing mentions 50,000 free download operations every month. The question is, are metadata reads counted in this limit or are metadata reads free?

Also, went through the Google Cloud Storage Pricing - my guess is that metadata reads shall be categorised as Small Operations and should be free?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Reference Links:

- https://firebase.google.com/pricing/
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

Answer (score 5):

We simplified our explanation of the pricing structure since we felt like it was confusing, so "Class A operations" == "Uploads" and "Class B operations" == "Downloads". In this case, metadata reads are "Downloads" or "Class B operations" per https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing

You get 20k "Class A/Upload" and 50k "Class B/Download" operations per day, per: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Mike! So its 50K operations per day and not month.

Comment: It's operations per day, yes, sorry for the confusion. Also, after closer inspection, it seems like it's only 20k "Uploads" per day, so we should probably update the pricing page and all.